# Dropbox Python API - Upload function

Tags: dropbox-api

Let's say that I upload a text file to Dropbox via Python API.

If I constantly append 1Mb of data per day and sync it, in the Day 10 will Dropbox upload all the 10Mb and replace the old file or just 1Mb and extend to the 9Mb file that have left?

Answer (score 1):

If you're uploading a file to Dropbox using the Dropbox Python SDK, e.g., with [the `files_upload` method](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_upload), the entire file contents has to be uploaded with every upload. The Dropbox API doesn't offer a way to just append to existing files, but I'll pass this along as a feature request.